# Why is VARCHAR slower than CHAR on updating rows?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I was reading a book :

> For example, when a column is defined as `VARCHAR(25)`, the maximum number of characters supported is 25, but in practice, the actual number of characters in the string determines the amount of storage. Because storage consumption 
>   for these data types is less than that for fixed-length types, read operations are faster. However, updates might result in row expansion, which might result in data movement outside the current page. Therefore, updates of data having variable-length data types are less efficient than updates of data having fixed-length data types.

I can understand that storage consumption for `varchar` is less than that for `char`, but why is it slower than `char` when updating records? What does row expansion mean and what actually happen when row expanses?

Let's say we have a suburb table which has two columns, `zipcode char(5)` and `name varchar`, and let's say we need to update a row's record with `zipcode` to be 10005, and `name` to be 'NYC', we only set 3 characters for the name column, shouldn't it be more efficient than `zipcode` column which requires 5 characters?

Comment: "why VARCHAR is faster then CHAR on updating rows?" contradicts "updates of data having variable-length data types are less efficient than updates of data having fixed-length data types".

Comment: First and foremost, your decision on which to use should be "which more closely resembles my requirements for the data?", not which one performs better. Do you have fixed length or variable length data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rows are laid out with the fixed size columns first, at *fixed* offsets from the start of the row. Then (after some important bytes in the middle) the variable sized data is placed at the end. Because it's variable sized, the actual offset to the data cannot be computed for the whole table (like the fixed data) but has to be computed on a row-by-row basis.

And if a `varchar(5)`<sup>1</sup> is storing `NYC` and is then asked to store `NYCX`, it may find that there's not a spare byte at the end of `NYC` - it's being used for another column - so the row has to *expand* by moving everything after one byte further along to make space for the extra byte.

---

<sup>1</sup>I notice in one of your examples you failed to specify a length. Please drill into yourself that [that's a bad habit](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: And a link for some extra information: https://aboutsqlserver.com/storage-engine/